# Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string in

Tags: fatal-error

i need help with this:

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string in /home/.../public_html/wp-content/themes/toroplay 2.1.2/inc/single-series.php on line 156
>   its this line: 153-156 :

```
$array_directors = array();
$term_list_directors = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'directors_tv', array("fields" => "all"));
if(!is_wp_error($term_list_directors) and !empty($term_list_directors)){
    foreach($term_list_directors as $director_single) { $array_directors[]='<a href="'.get_term_link($director_single->term_id, 'directors').'">'.$director_single->name.'</a>'; }
```

Comment: And which is line 156?

Comment: foreach($term_list_directors as $director_single) { $array_directors[]='<a href="'.get_term_link($director_single->term_id, 'directors').'">'.$director_single->name.'</a>'; }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the terms of `directors_tv` taxonomy, but try to get the next link in the context of `directors` taxonomy. You probably should use `directors_tv` in both places or rethink your DB structure as you can not use the same term id in the context of different taxonomies.